# DMA engine API vs DMA API

Tags: linux, dma

Can someone briefly explain the usage of both and what the difference?

Note: I have read the linux documentation

Comment: The Linux DMA-API focuses on ensuring that the I/O buffers used are accessible by the DMA controller, and providing address conversions ("mappings") for the device driver.  This API is for I/O buffer management and prepping the DMA controller.  The DMA Engine API specifies an interface to the actual DMA controller hardware functionality and initiating/cleaning-up transfers.

Comment: @sawdust, You could have written this as an answer.